# Typescript for redux actions

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to build a reducer object that will use type guard based on the action type. I would like to have something like this:

```
const myReducers: ReducerMap<MyState, FirstAction | SecondAction> = {
  [FIRST]: (s, a) => s // a should be automatically cast to FirstAction with type guards
  [SECOND]: (s, a) => s // a should be automatically cast to FirstAction with type guards
}

const FIRST = 'FIRST';
const SECOND = 'SECOND';

interface FirstAction extends Action<typeof FIRST> {some: string}
interface SecondAction extends Action<typeof Second> {some: string}
```

With a switch case, I can make it work because the type guard will filter on the different `type` types.

```
function test(s: {}, a: LoadAction | DataAction) {
    switch (a.type) {
        case LOAD_EVENT:
            return { ...s, id: a.id }; // auto cast to LoadAction
        case LOAD_EVENT_SUCCESS:
            return { ...s, ...a.data }; // auto cast to DataAction
    }

    return s;
}
```

But in an object I'm not able to do it.

I've tried the following with only return all the possible actions:

```
type ActionFilter<A extends Action, T extends string> = {[P in T]: P extends A['type'] ? A : never}[T];

let x: ActionFilter<LoadAction | DataAction, typeof LOAD_EVENT>;
// expected x: LoadAction, but got x: LoadAction | DataAction
```

I've also tried the following but it does not compile

```
interface ReducerMap<S, A extends Action> {
    [key: typeof A['type']]: (s: S, a: A) => S;
    // 'A' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
    // An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it

```
type ActionFilter<A extends Action, T extends string> = {[P in T]: A extends Action<T> ? A : never}[T];
```

So apparently I cannot compare with Action['type'] because the type is any at this point, but I can check if my action extends the correct action type.